# How to add a string to regular expressions in SQL and then convert it to a date?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in which one of the columns contains strings of the following format:

```
Info
ENGLISH.JOHN.BROWN.MAR.92
GERMAN.TIM.OLIVER.JAN.95
```

I am using regular expressions to convert the 3 letter month and 2 digit year at the end of the string to a date. However, I need the day in the date to be the 15th of each month, then use that date to calculate the day difference from today.Below is my code:

```
  SELECT (TO_DATE(('15.'+(REGEXP_SUBSTR(Info, '[A-Z]{3}\.\d{2}'))), 'DD.MON.RR')-to_date('17-SEP-19', 'DD-MON-YY')) AS DAY_DIFF FROM my_table
```

I am getting an error saying invalid number.Could you please advise me what am I doing wrong in joining the strings?

I am using Toad for Oracle and my actual table has hundreds of rows so I need each one to be converted as shown above.

Comment: Concatenation operator in Oracle SQL is `||`

Comment: `trunc(sysdate)` will give you today's date in Oracle SQL.

Comment: I tried the concat operator but I just end up with 15. instead of 15.MAR.92 for example.

Comment: I don't know what you did, but it works fine for me. [dbfiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c18bb3080f64b8ff95d1f68c104b5373)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you "select to_date" you will get a result in date format and you can then add a number, not a string to that result. This is the reason your select is getting error. You are trying to add '15.' insetead of 15

This will give you 15th of the month:

```
SELECT 14 + TO_DATE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(Info, '[A-Z]{3}\.\d{2}'), 'MON.RR') FROM my_table;
```

Then from this you can substract your date:

```
select (14 + TO_DATE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(Info, '[A-Z]{3}\.\d{2}'), 'MON.RR')) - to_date('17-SEP-19', 'DD-MON-YY') AS DAY_DIFF FROM my_table
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: If the user has different session parameters then your query can fail (without changing the SQL). I.e. `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = 'FRENCH';` [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f0f9e5e3e0453da2a14c1af3773a3528)

Comment: Yes, you are right, I have seen that already on another comment. Because the user is having problems with ORA-01722: invalid number and not "ORA-01843: not a valid month" I have tried to help him with his problem and not to create some new confusion. I believe my answer is resolving all that he asked: "How to add to regesxp" and addition to that "explanation of the error". Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `SUBSTR( Info, -6 )` to get the last 6 characters of the string. `TO_DATE( value, 'MON.RR' )` will convert to a date at the first of the month (however, since you are using an abbreviated month name, it would be better to also specify the `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` you are using so it does not default to the user's session value). You can then add 14 days to it and find the difference from `TRUNC( SYSDATE )` (today's date truncated back to midnight).

Like this:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table ( Info ) As
SELECT 'ENGLISH.JOHN.BROWN.MAR.92' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GERMAN.TIM.OLIVER.JAN.95'  FROM DUAL
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT ( TO_DATE(
           SUBSTR( info, -6 ),
           'MON.RR',
           'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = AMERICAN'
         ) + INTERVAL '14' DAY
       ) AS parsed_date,
       TRUNC( SYSDATE ) -
       ( TO_DATE(
           SUBSTR( info, -6 ),
           'MON-RR',
           'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = AMERICAN'
         ) + INTERVAL '14' DAY
       )
       AS day_diff
FROM   my_table
```

**Output**:

> ```
> PARSED_DATE | DAY_DIFF
> :---------- | -------:
> 15-MAR-92   |    10047
> 15-JAN-95   |     9011
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cbe3a3616a7af7b47154aaacf827e354)*

Answer (score 1):

```
create table t(Info) as
select 'ENGLISH.JOHN.BROWN.MAR.92' from dual union all
select 'GERMAN.TIM.OLIVER.JAN.95' from dual;

select info,
  substr(info, -6) dte_string,
  to_date(
    substr(info, -6),
    'MON.RR',
    'nls_date_language=''ENGLISH'''
  ) + 14 dte,
  trunc(sysdate) - 
    to_date(
      substr(info, -6),
      'MON.RR',
      'nls_date_language=''ENGLISH'''
    ) - 14 day_diff
from t;

INFO                       DTE_STRING  DTE        DAY_DIFF   
ENGLISH.JOHN.BROWN.MAR.92  MAR.92      1992-03-15    10047 
GERMAN.TIM.OLIVER.JAN.95   JAN.95      1995-01-15     9011
```

Comment: If the user has different session parameters then your query can fail (without changing the SQL). I.e. `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = 'FRENCH';` [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e4817ef2e988519bfc8b11e4616d1675)

Comment: True. Corrected the answer.

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption that all of your clients are all configured to use the same language, (which is not at all unusual).

Here's an alternative solution:

```
WITH my_table AS 
    (SELECT 'ENGLISH.JOHN.BROWN.MAR.92' AS info FROM dual)
SELECT TRUNC(TO_DATE('15-'||SUBSTR( info, -6 ),'DD-MON-RR')) - TRUNC(sysdate) AS day_diff 
FROM my_table
```

Comment: If the user has different session parameters then your query can fail (without changing the SQL). I.e. `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = 'FRENCH';` [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1f4307c29d00b708f7f24d13733f4343)

Comment: I never said anything about any particular language. By not providing a `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` as a 3rd parameter to `TO_DATE` you are allowing the query to implicitly assume that it should use the session's NLS parameters and if this implicitly assumed value does not match the data then *your query will fail*. Since each user can set their own session parameters at any time (and may have different defaults depending on the internationalisation settings chosen on installation) then it seems that making assumptions could create risks that the query will fail for some users with different settings.

Comment: You misunderstood too. Yes, a typical individual user's session has fixed settings but in an international environment many users can have many default settings, not necessarily all English, so expecting to use the user session's defaults you are setting your query up to fail if you do not tell it the language the data uses. Instead, if the data is multiple languages then the query is going to fail regardless of which single language you choose and you'd need extra information to decode it. So if you know the data's language then specify it in the query don't assume it equals the sessions.